# Выравнивание по байтам

Tags: c++, c, malloc

Допустим если я выделяю память `void* a=malloc(3)` то число 3 не кратно четным числам,а значит из ресурсов что я вычитал сказано,что выделение мне даст не за одну итерацию памяти,а за 2. И значит что процесс будет слегка дольше работать чем с выравненной памятью.

1. Правильно ли я мыслю?
2. Выравнивание нужно делать по длине байт машинного слова `WORD`? или двойного слова `DWORD`?
3. Предположим я узнал значение выравнивания `=2`,это значит что я могу выравнивать на всё что кратно `2` или только на `2` ?
4. **Вопрос-бонус(для меня)** Выравнивание по `16` используется для SSE?() т.е. `8` регистров,каждый по `2` байта и типо `8*2=16`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> то число 3 не кратно четным числам,а значит из ресурсов что я вычитал сказано,что выделение мне даст не за одну итерацию памяти,а за 2

нет. абсолютно неверно. Покажите, что Вы читаете. Возможно, пропускаете некоторые слова.

Скорее всего void* a=malloc(3) выделит от 4 байт и больше, как будет удобно менеджеру памяти. У него накладные расходы на выделение блока памяти могут быть сильно больше.

> Правильно ли я мыслю?

не уверен:)

> Выравнивание нужно делать по длине байт машинного слова WORD? или двойного слова DWORD?

по ситуации. Иногда по границе 4 байта, иногда 8. Надо смотреть в каждом конкретном случае. Но обычно выравнивание по границе в 16 почти всегда хватает. Есть случаи, когда выравнивают по 1024.

> Предположим я узнал значение выравнивания =2,это значит что я могу выравнивать на всё что кратно 2 или только на 2 ?

не любое, что делится на 2 нацело. допустим, 6 или 18

> Вопрос-бонус(для меня) Выравнивание по 16 используется для SSE?() т.е. 8 регистров,каждый по 2 байта и типо 8*2=16?

многие SSE инструкции либо не будут работать, либо будут "подтормаживать", если данные не выровнены. Да, для некоторых нужно по границе в 16 байт, если так сказано в документации.

Comment: _по ситуации_ Например? Я хочу разобраться основательно)

Comment: например, если Вы работаете на ARM (купили на последнее новый M1 от эппл или просто под телефон), то данные лучше выровнять на границу в 4 байта, а то при попытке обратится к не выровненному адресу процессор скажет "ай-ай" и сделает исключение. Некоторые функции требуют выравнивания - нужно смотреть в документациях на конкретную функцию.

Comment: Может глупый вопрос,но знание о границе выравнивания это личный опыт?  либо это какой-то пергамент который называется "**ВЫРАВНИВАНИЕ ПО ГРАНИЦЕ**"

Comment: это сакральное знание, которое передается по наследству:)